# Child processes not running concurrently

Tags: c++, linux, fork, child-process

So I am writing a hotel reservation system where I have hotel rooms stored in shared memory and will have an x number of customers reserve, cancel, pay, etc the rooms. Each customer will be a child process and they should all be running concurrently, trying to do the stated transactions to the rooms.

Here is my code for forking the child processes:

```
int pid[10];
for(int i = 0; i < numOfCustomers; i++) {
    pid[i] = fork();
    if(pid[i] < 0) {
        perror("Bad fork");
    }
    else if(pid[i] == 0) { //is child i (Each customer is a child process)
        cout << "CUSTOMER: " << i << endl;
        while(!customers[i].transactions.empty()) { //runs until customer finishes all transactions
            string op = customers[i].transactions.front();
            if(op == "reserve") {
                if(sem_wait(semid, 0))
                    exit(1);
                Reserve tempq = customers[i].reservequeue.front();
                for(int i = 0; i < tempq.roomcounter; i++) {
                    int roomnum = tempq.roomqueue.front();
                    if(shared_memory[roomnum-1].isavailable == true) {
                        shared_memory[roomnum-1].isavailable = false;
                        shared_memory[roomnum-1].day = tempq.day;
                        shared_memory[roomnum-1].month = tempq.month;
                        shared_memory[roomnum-1].year = tempq.year;
                        shared_memory[roomnum-1].customer = cust;
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "Room " << roomnum << " already taken." << endl;
                    }
                    tempq.roomqueue.pop();
                }
                customers[i].reservequeue.pop();
                if(sem_signal(semid, 0))
                    exit(1);
            }
            else if(op == "cancel") { //not done yet
                cout << "cancel" << endl; 
            }
            else if(op == "check") { //not done yet
                cout << "check" << endl;
            }
            else if(op == "pay") { //not done yet
                cout << "pay" << endl;
            }
            customers[i].transactions.pop();
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else { //is parent

    }
}

//waits for each process to finish
for (int i = 0; i < numOfCustomers; i++) {
    wait(NULL);
}
```

The problem is that it does everything in child one first, finishes, then does everything in child 2. Processes aren't running concurrently which defeats the whole purpose of having shared memory and using semaphores.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think I can pretty much guarantee that no sensible hotel reservation system would use such a convoluted architecture.

Comment: @NeilButterworth it's a programming assignment to learn about shared memory and semaphore usage.

Comment: Have you tried adding delays, to ensure that the first child lasts long enough to come into conflict with the second?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what platform are you doing this on? I ask because every [`sem_wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sem_wait.html) I've ever used (linux, osx, hpux, solaris, aix, etc) *all* take a single argument: the sem ptr itself.

Comment: @WhozCraig using linux, I made a sem_signal and sem_wait function to avoid having to make a struct and doing semop every time I need to signal and wait.

Comment: @Beta after adding some sleep() statements around, I can see that they are running concurrently. Any idea why child 0 always starts first though? I was under the impression that the OS decided which child process to run first

Comment: @Bzm10823 Unless something is different, why shouldn't it run the same child first each time?

Comment: `semop()`? You're using old school SYSV semaphores with a custom function that shares a name with the POSIX semaphore API? That's unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: I wonder if your sem_signal function is really releasing the semaphore. If not, the first process to gain ownership would keep it until the process exits, which might produce the behaviour you are seeing.